# How to get Metric Units from Amazon Cloudwatch?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

### Background

I'm making some calls to the [AmazonCloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)  api and can successfully receiving data back using the `GetMetricDataAsync`and `ListMetricsAsync` calls. However the data returned does not include what unit that data actually is.

For example: *Bytes* or *Percent*

Without the Units, I'm unable to meaningfully display the collect data.

*Side note: I'm using the C# SDK.*

### Question

Is it possible to retrieve the Units for the Metrics data?

### Example data received

```
{
        "id": "q21",
        "label": "DiskWriteBytes",
        "messages": [],
        "statusCode": {
            "value": "PartialData"
        },
        "timestamps": ["2019-01-14T14:58:00+00:00", "2019-01-14T14:53:00+00:00", "2019-01-14T14:48:00+00:00"],
        "values": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    }, {
        "id": "q22",
        "label": "NetworkIn",
        "messages": [],
        "statusCode": {
            "value": "PartialData"
        },
        "timestamps": ["2019-01-14T14:58:00+00:00", "2019-01-14T14:53:00+00:00", "2019-01-14T14:48:00+00:00"],
        "values": [21136.0, 21556.8, 20118.6]
    }, {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the example response, you're using the GetMetricData API. GetMetricData API will not return the unit, see here for the response data structure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDataResult.html

If you set the unit in the request, API will filter by the unit, so any data returned will be with the unit requested.

If you don't set the unit and data exists with multiple units, message will be returned stating which units were found.

If you don't know the unit upfront and need to get it from the data, you can use GetMetricStatistics API, which will return the unit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricStat.html

Comment: Perfect, do I really need to request each metric/unit individually though?

Comment: Yeah, you can only request 1 metric with GetMetricStatistics.